# Настроил связку VPS(Ubuntu) + uWSGI + NGINX + Django. Но стартовая страница открывается Apache2

Tags: ubuntu, django, nginx, uwsgi

Настроил связку VPS(Ubuntu) + uWSGI + NGINX + Django. Все работает если открывать domain.com:8000. В свою очередь если просто набрать domain.com, открывается Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. Не могу понять в чем моя ошибка. Спасибо.

**Nginx / sites-available**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user/uwsgi/domain.sock;
    }
}
```

**sudo nginx -t**

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

**sudo systemctl status nginx**

```
nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-04-30 23:48:08 CEST; 1h 11min ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
 Main PID: 753 (nginx)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 1110)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─753 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
           ├─754 nginx: worker process
           └─755 nginx: cache manager process

Apr 30 23:48:08 fornex.org systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Apr 30 23:48:08 fornex.org systemd[1]: nginx.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/nginx.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Apr 30 23:48:08 fornex.org systemd[1]: Started nginx - high performance web server.
```

**sudo systemctl status apache2**

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server

   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-04-30 23:48:08 CEST; 1h 12min ago
 Main PID: 769 (apache2)
    Tasks: 8 (limit: 1110)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─ 769 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 770 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 774 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 775 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 776 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 778 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─ 781 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─1813 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Apr 30 23:48:07 fornex.org systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 30 23:48:08 fornex.org systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Comment: Вывод `sudo nginx -t` и `sudo systemctl status nginx` и `sudo systemctl status apache2` в студию

Comment: Добавил "выводы" в вопрос!

Comment: Поправьте порт апача на любой другой. А в конфиг nginx назначьте с 8000 на 80, если я правильно понял как должна работать эта связка. А кто на чем висит удобнее через `sudo netstat -ntlp`, но сначала надо поставить этот пакет `sudo apt install net-tools`